# How do scenes and stages work in telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I've searched telegram bot api for "scenes" and "stages" that are part of [telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=stage). [Here](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/develop/docs/examples/scenes-bot.js) is an example. It seems they are implementations of telegraf and not the API. If this is the case how does telegraf implement those?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read this tutorial on using Scenes and Stages here: https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/705